Yfinance Python Library returns different result from NASDAQ
I am using yfinance to get information about USOI ticker.
tickerSymbol = 'USOI'

#get data on this ticker
tickerData = yf.Ticker(tickerSymbol)

#get the historical prices for this ticker
db = tickerData.history(period='1d',start = '2020-10-14', end = '2024-10-17')

db['Close'][0:10], db.index[0:10]

Returns
Date
 2020-10-14 00:00:00-04:00    32.161522
 2020-10-15 00:00:00-04:00    32.234608
 2020-10-16 00:00:00-04:00    32.088417
 2020-10-19 00:00:00-04:00    32.088417
 2020-10-20 00:00:00-04:00    32.324036
 2020-10-21 00:00:00-04:00    31.587734
 2020-10-22 00:00:00-04:00    32.324036
 2020-10-23 00:00:00-04:00    31.808615
 2020-10-26 00:00:00-04:00    31.219574
 2020-10-27 00:00:00-04:00    31.514090

But if I check NASDAQ website https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/etf/usoi/historical?page=101&rows_per_page=10&timeline=y10
I get different values.

What is going on?

The problem is the difference between the two sources of data. It is not a programming-related question.

It is common to use yfinance in Python to extract data, however, if yfinance and NASDAQ data differs.... this is disturbing.

I ran your code and got the same results. Did you try to check USOI data at finance.yahoo.com?
